# problem with raiseerror()

Tags: sql, sql-server, raiseerror

what I want to do is to create a stored procedure that executes insert statement.There is a possibility the execution to fail because of a check constraint for the table Employee.In that case I want to handle a user-defined error.Obviously the following procedure is not working properly because it always raises my error,but not only when insertion fails.

```
EXEC sp_addmessage 50001, 16, N'Title must be one of the following - Captain,Engineer,Flight-attendant,Purser,First-officer';

CREATE PROCEDURE InsertIntoEmployee

 @firstName nvarchar(30),
 @familyName nvarchar(30),
 @title nvarchar(50), 
 @address nvarchar(50), 
 @chiefID int , 
 @salary money ,
 @FK_IDCrew int,
 @FK_DepartmentID int 

AS
BEGIN 
declare @err_num int;
declare @err_sev int;
declare @err_msg int;

begin try
insert into Employee(firstName, familyName, title, address, chiefID, salary, FK_IDCrew,
FK_DepartmentID)
values(@firstName, @familyName, @title, @address, @chiefID, @salary, @FK_IDCrew,
@FK_DepartmentID);

raiserror(50001,16,1);
END try 
begin catch
set  @err_num=ERROR_NUMBER();
set @err_sev=ERROR_SEVERITY();
set @err_msg=ERROR_STATE();
raiserror(@err_num,@err_sev,@err_msg);
end catch 
end
GO
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to do: it will always hit the RAISERROR in this code. There is no check to match the RAISERROR either

Answer (score 0):

In this case:

- Title should be a lookup to another table and a foreign key
- In the CATCH block you can trap the FK constraint violation separately if you want...
- ...but you'd only allow rows from the new table in your client so I wouldn't personally
- No need for a sys.messages entry

Your code will also always hit the RAISERROR too which doesn't add any value,

Answer (score 0):

1. I hope that the dimensions mentioned in the parameter list is sycn with table columns length.
2. Before **insertion**, You should check take care of following points.

   Check the existence of **@FK_IDCrew** value in it's table.

   Check the existence of **@FK_DepartmentID** value in it's table.

It should be like below.

```
If Not Exists(Select IDCrewColumnName From Table Where columnName = @FK_IDCrew)
Begin
    return here from the stored procedure.
End
```

In case any of them fails to meet the conditions, you should show some user friendly message to user that

(a) **Crew ID**, you are going to insert, either deleted or does not exists in the database.

(b) **DepartmentID**, you are going to insert, either deleted or does not exists in the database.

In this way the probability of error will also come to an end.